# Core 3.1 API in ServiceFabric Solution, Local Secrets Not Read

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, secretsmanager

I am pulling my hair out right about now.  I have tried getting the Secrets multiple different ways.  Here is where I am at:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //Configuration = configuration;  // <<=== THIS DOES NOT WORK - CONFIG IS ALWAYS EMPTY ===

        // Manually add configuration...
        var app = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(env.ApplicationName));
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true) // When app is published
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        if (app != null && env.IsDevelopment())
            builder.AddUserSecrets(app, optional: false);

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySqlConn");
        var password = Configuration["MyPassword"];  // <<===  THIS FAILS - ALWAYS NULL ===
        var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
        builder.Password = password;
        connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;

        services.AddDbContext<MySqlContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API v1"); c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty; });

        if (!env.IsProduction())
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
    }
}
```

When I check via the CLI I can see that the secret(s) are set correctly

> dotnet user-secrets list
> MyPassword = *************

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi @Keith,It could work well with setting `Configuration = configuration; ` in development environment. Could you set the log to trace level to check if there contains exception when you use `Configuration = configuration; `?Also what environment you use?Development or Production?From your manually add configuration,you miss adding `secrets.json` file.

Comment: Hosting SF local is done in a Docker Container.  Without getting into mapping folders to be accessible inside of Docker, the Secrets location is unreachable.  I moved Secrets.json to my app root and marked it in .gitignore.  A hack, but it is works.  Env=Dev, local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service Fabric, when run local, is run within a Docker Container.  This means that the folder the Secrets.json file is located on natively is inaccessible to anything running in the container.  For the short term (hack) I moved the secrets.json to my app root folder (with appsettings.json) and marked it in my .gitignore so it is not checked in.  I also added it to the above configuration code.  Works fine but the default Configuration will never find it there so i am keeping my hand rolled configuration builder.

Comment: I've been fighting the same problem! What a pain!